# DateTime with timezone deserialization problem

Tags: asp.net-core, datetime, timezone, deserialization

I am expecting in a dotnet 6 api an incoming request with JSON body, with a property that is a timestamp in ISO8601 format with timezone information, e.g. 2018-01-01T12:01:13.252+0200

My controller cannot deserialize the above value, and returns a 400 response.

If I omit the last two zeros in the timestamp, i.e. use 2018-01-01T12:01:13.252+02 everything works perfectly.

Also, if I create a GET endpoint that accepts a datetime in query string, everything works ok both with +0200 and with +02 as timezone information.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, can anybody give a clue ?

Controller code:

```
public record TestRequest(DateTime Timestamp);

[HttpPost("test")]
public IActionResult TestNested([FromBody] TestRequest request)
{
    return Ok(request.Timestamp.ToUniversalTime());
}
```

Request sample - INVALID w/ 400 Response

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://whatever' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "timestamp": "2022-10-08T14:45:08.890+0200"
}'
```

The response I am getting is

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-be3ecd4cc3611f6e7a359d59c279afc2-9b36d6d2ec59b589-00",
  "errors": {
    "request": [
      "The request field is required."
    ],
    "$.timestamp": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to [....].TestRequest. Path: $.timestamp | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 45."
    ]
  }
```

Request sample - VALID w/ 200 Response (notice the last two zeros missing from the timezone)

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://whatever' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "timestamp": "2022-10-08T14:45:08.890+02"
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `2018-01-01T12:01:13.252+0200` is malformed because it is missing a `:` separating the hours and minutes in the offset.  It should be `2018-01-01T12:01:13.252+02:00`.

If you must pass it without the colon, you will need to create a custom `JsonConverter` to do the parsing.  See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support) for examples.

Also, since your data contains time zone offsets, you should probably be using `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime`.

---

To elaborate a bit more about the format, current versions of ASP.NET Core use `System.Text.Json`, which expects timestamps to be in the ISO 8601-1:2019 extended profile representation.   This is commonly known simply as "ISO 8601", but that specification has many different formats within it.

In ISO 8601's nomenclature the format that applies is called a "complete representation of date and time of day" (yes, it's quite verbose).  There are two valid formats for such representation - "basic format" and "extended format".

- The "basic" format omits almost all punctuation, except for the sign preceding the offset and a decimal separator for fractional seconds.  (`System.Text.Json` doesn't use this format by default.)

  The following are both valid examples:

  ```
  20180101T120113.252+02
  20180101T120113.252+0200
  ```
- By contrast, the "extended" format *requires* all punctuation.  (This is the format `System.Text.Json` understands.)

  The following are both valid examples:

  ```
  2018-01-01T12:01:13.252+02
  2018-01-01T12:01:13.252+02:00
  ```

In both cases, the offset can be specified in terms of whole hours, or in hours and minutes.  Though the spec supports both, it's reasonable to always pass the minutes, since many time zones are 30 minutes offset (and some are 45).

The ISO 8601 spec does *not* allow mixing the basic and extended formats.  Thus one *must* include the `:` to be compliant.  A similar specification for the extended format can be found in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6), which also requires the colon separator.

Comment: BTW, Another interesting anecdote about ISO 8601 is that it allows either the a comma (`,`) or a period (`.`) to separate seconds from fractional seconds, and it states that it *prefers* the comma.  However, RFC 3339 only allows the period, as do most parsers that claim to be ISO 8601 compliant - including `System.Text.Json`.  So stick with the period (`.`)

Comment: Actually, a minor correction to my last comment - the 2004 edition of ISO 8601 stated that the comma was prefered, but that language was removed in the 2019 edition.  Both are still allowed, but there's no preference indicated.  Still, in computing for compatibility with RFC3339 and the vast majority of parsers out there, I'd use a period.  (Sorry for the tangent!)

Comment: The incoming request is produced by another API , over which I have no control. So, I guess I can notify them that the format they are using is NOT valid ISO 8601, as they claim... Thank you for the explanation! If there is no other way, I will have to try and write a custom JsonConverter.

Comment: In the meantime, I have found out that DateTimeOffset.Parse("2018-01-01T12:01:13.252+0200") works as expected even with the malformed string. This seems weird, since I don't see why DateTimeOffset.Parse() works but json deserialization doesn't.